# Unity object pooling works for first ten seconds and then all objects go deactivated. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity and have created a simple infinite runner game. I have two types of platforms that spawn on the screen infinitely. When I was using instantiate and destroy the to spawn and delete platforms, they worked fine. Now that I am pooling my objects I am having a problem.

I have an object pooling script that creates the pool and has a method that grabs an object. When each platform has spawned that platform then spawns the next platform. The pool works at first, platforms spawn, deactivate, and then call the next platform; However, this does not last long before all platforms go deactivated. It seems as if the problem begins to occur after each platform has been spawned once.

```
public class ObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject pooledObject1;
    public GameObject pooledObject2;
    public int numPooled;
    List<GameObject> pool1;
    List<GameObject> pool2;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        pool1 = new List<GameObject>();
        pool2 = new List<GameObject>();

        // Creating pool for first type of object. 
        for (int i = 0; i < numPooled; i++)
        {
            GameObject obj1 = (GameObject)Instantiate(pooledObject1);
            obj1.SetActive(false);
            pool1.Add(obj1);
        }

        // Creating pool for second type of object.
        for (int i = 0; i < numPooled; i++)
        {
            GameObject obj2 = (GameObject)Instantiate(pooledObject2);
            obj2.SetActive(false);
            pool2.Add(obj2);
        }

    }

    // Grabs an object from the pool. 
    public GameObject getObject1()
    {
        // Retrieving the first type of object. 
        for (int i = 0; i <= pool1.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!pool1[i].activeInHierarchy)
            {
                return pool1[i];
            }
        }

        GameObject obj1 = (GameObject)Instantiate(pooledObject1);
        obj1.SetActive(false);
        pool1.Add(obj1);

        return null;   
    }

    public GameObject getObject2()
    {
        // Retrieving the second type of object. 
        for (int i = 0; i <= pool2.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!pool2[i].activeInHierarchy)
            {
                return pool2[i];
            }
        }

       GameObject obj2 = (GameObject)Instantiate(pooledObject2);
       obj2.SetActive(false);
       pool2.Add(obj2);

        return null;
    }
}

public class PlatformGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

    // Variable field for the random number that will determine platform spacing. 
    float waitingTime;
    float timer;

    // Variables for Position of next platform. 
    float yPos;
    float xPos;

    // Variable for the next platform spawned by current platform. 
    public GameObject newPlatform;
    public ObjectPooler pool; 

    // Variable for the collider. 
    public BoxCollider2D boxCollider;

    /**
     * Use this for initialization
     */
    void Start () {
        waitingTime = Random.Range(1f, 1.35f);
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    /**
     * Update is called once per frame
     */
    void Update () {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer > waitingTime)
        {
            createPlatform();
            timer = -20;
        }

        ensurePosition();
    } 

    /**
     * This method creates a new platform object when the counter is 0.
     */
     public void createPlatform()
    {
        // Generate relatively random number for y position of new platform. 
        yPos = Random.Range(transform.position.y - 20, transform.position.y + 20);
        xPos = 235;

        // Create the new platform at given y coordinate. 
        //Instantiate(this, new Vector2(xPos, yPos), Quaternion.identity);

        if (gameObject.tag == "BrownPlatform")
        {
            newPlatform = pool.getObject1();
            newPlatform.SetActive(true);
            newPlatform.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
            newPlatform.transform.position = new Vector2(xPos, yPos);
        }
        else 
        {
            newPlatform = pool.getObject2();
            newPlatform.SetActive(true);
            newPlatform.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
            newPlatform.transform.position = new Vector2(xPos, yPos);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method ensures the y position is appropriate. 
     */
     private void ensurePosition()
    {
        // Checks for yPos above the screen. 
        if (transform.position.y > 75f)
        {

            int offsetY =  Random.Range(20, 100);
            yPos = transform.position.y - offsetY;
            transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, yPos);
        }

        // Checks for yPos below screen.
        if (transform.position.y < -75f)
        {
            yPos = transform.position.y + 5;
            transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, yPos);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with the following portion of the code

```
for (int i = 0; i <= pool1.Count; i++)
{
    if (!pool1[i].activeInHierarchy)
    {
        return pool1[i];
    }
}

GameObject obj1 = (GameObject)Instantiate(pooledObject1);
obj1.SetActive(false);
pool1.Add(obj1);

return null;
```

Once the pools is exhausted, you're adding the new object to the pool, but instead of returning that object you're returning null.

return statement should be

```
return obj1;
```

Same goes for the second method.

Also instead of repeating the code, you can create two `ObjectPooler` instances, one for each type of object.

Pool instantiation can be done manually in the Platform code, since you're not using `ObjectPooler` as `MonoBehavior`.

**Edit** *

Here's a simple implementation of an object pool

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class ObjectPool {

    private List<GameObject> poolList;
    private int initialSize;
    private GameObject prefab;
    private Func<GameObject> instantiationMethod;//Use this to do custom processing

    public ObjectPool(GameObject prefab, int initialSize)
    {
        this.prefab = prefab;
        this.initialSize = initialSize;

        createPool();
    }

    public ObjectPool(GameObject prefab, int initialSize, Func<GameObject> instantiationMethod)
    {
        this.prefab = prefab;
        this.initialSize = initialSize;
        this.instantiationMethod = instantiationMethod;

        createPool();
    }

    private List<GameObject> createPool()
    {
        poolList = new List<GameObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < initialSize; i++)
        {
            createNewPoolObject();
        }

        return poolList;
    }

    private GameObject createNewPoolObject()
    {
        GameObject poolEntry = null;

        poolEntry = (instantiationMethod == null) ? MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(prefab) : instantiationMethod();

        poolEntry.SetActive(false);
        poolList.Add(poolEntry);

        return poolEntry;
    }

    public GameObject get()
    {
        GameObject poolElement = poolList.Find(obj => !obj.activeInHierarchy);

        if(poolElement == null)
        {
            poolElement = createNewPoolObject();
        }

        return poolElement;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return poolList.Count;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ObjectPoolInstantiator : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject pool1Prefab;
    public GameObject pool2Prefab;

    private ObjectPool pool1;
    private ObjectPool pool2;

    void Start () {
        pool1 = new ObjectPool(pool1Prefab, 5);
        pool2 = new ObjectPool(pool2Prefab, 5);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            GameObject pool1Element = pool1.get();
            pool1Element.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log("poo1 size : " + pool1.size());

            GameObject pool2Element = pool2.get();
            pool2Element.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log("poo2 size : " + pool2.size());
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have added a constructor with instantiation method, in case you want to do something extra when instantiating the object like setting it's position, parent etc.

Comment: Even after making this fix the same problem occurs. Now that I look back I don't understand how it worked at all with returning null.

Comment: I have added a simple implementation of the ObjectPool to the answer, please take a look at it.

Comment: The problem persists even after trying to use multiple different implementations of a pool. What I have observed is that items are easily set true and false and objects are put into the pool. My current method is using a queue and I have observed that I am successfully enqueue'ing everything but when the many clones are exhausted, the original platforms are next in the queue but they do not dequeue (I have confirmed that using Peek).